# Unable to retrieve private key in classpath through spring config from jar- File inside jar is not visible to spring

Tags: java, spring-integration

Can someone Please suggest me.I have Spring application which is standalone and deployed as Windows service(all this code goes into JAR). I have a piece of config to connect to sftp gateway,which requires private key and it is placed in classpath. So the below config to retrieve privatekey file from classpath doesnt seem to work. I understood from other blogs that this problem is due to the file present in classpath of jar. My code is as follows.

```
`<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
<property name="host" value="${abc.host}" />
<property name="privateKey" value="classpath*:/SRVKeyfile" />
<property name="user" value="${abc.user}" />
<property name="port" value="${abc.port}" />
```

`
I tried different ways to get the private key, but nothing seems to work aand it throws Filenotfound exception.
Error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:/SRVKeyfile] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Actually `privateKey` property of the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` is `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. Therefore any valid `resource location` can be specified for that property from config: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

From here you can place your file somewhere in the file system and just use `file://` location for that Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My requirement got changed i.e. to put the private key file in filesystem and your suggestion helped :). Thanks much!. btw do you have any suggestions if in case, key is required to be put in classpath?..

Comment: Well. In that case `key` can be in the one of your jars or just in the directory which you add to the classpath of your application using `java -cp C:/.../jardir1/*;C:/.../jardir2/* class_with_main_method`